# Sqlite View does not use index for left join queries

Tags: sqlite, indexing, view, union

In Sqlite, I defined a view as a union all of two tables. When I run queries using that view, the index is used if the query is simple enough.  For certain complex queries, it does not and ends up running full table scans.  Are there ways around this so that I can use views performantly?

### Table/View Definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE 'Table1'     (Id varchar (18) PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK,    Name varchar (255)    )
CREATE TABLE 'Table2'     (Id varchar (18) PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK,    Name varchar (255)    )
CREATE TABLE 'Table3'     (Id varchar (18) PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK,    Name varchar (255)    )
CREATE VIEW [UnionView] AS SELECT 'T1' tid, T1.rowid, T1.* FROM [Table1] T1 UNION ALL SELECT 'T2' tid, T2.rowid, T2.* FROM [Table2] T2
```

### Simple Query (indexes are used):

```
SELECT Id FROM [UnionView] WHERE Id = 'asdf'
```

#### Explain Query Plan:

1. COMPOUND QUERY
2. LEFT-MOST SUBQUERY
3. **SEARCH TABLE** Table1 AS T1 USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Table1_1 (Id=?)
4. UNION ALL
5. **SEARCH TABLE** Table2 AS T2 USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Table2_1 (Id=?)

### LEFT JOIN Query (indexes are not used):

```
SELECT T3.Id FROM [Table3] T3 LEFT JOIN [UnionView] T ON T3.Id=T.Id  WHERE T3.Id = 'asdf'
```

#### Explain Query Plan

1. MATERIALIZE 2
2. COMPOUND QUERY
3. LEFT-MOST SUBQUERY
4. **SCAN TABLE** Table1 AS T1
5. UNION ALL
6. **SCAN TABLE** Table2 AS T2
7. SEARCH TABLE Table3 AS T3 USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Table3_1 (Id=?)
8. SCAN SUBQUERY 2 AS T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *complex* query does full table scans of `Table1` and `Table2` because you are not doing any filtering on `UnionView`.
It does use though `sqlite_autoindex_Table3_1`.
Also, the `WHERE` clause is applied after the joins.

If you filter `UnionView` before the join then indexes will be used:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN 
SELECT T3.Id 
FROM [Table3] T3 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Id FROM [UnionView] WHERE Id = 'asdf') T 
ON T3.Id=T.Id  
WHERE T3.Id = 'asdf'
```

Result:

- MATERIALIZE 3
- COMPOUND QUERY
- LEFT-MOST SUBQUERY
- SEARCH TABLE Table1 AS T1 USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Table1_1 (Id=?)
- UNION ALL
- SEARCH TABLE Table2 AS T2 USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Table2_1 (Id=?)
- SEARCH TABLE Table3 AS T3 USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Table3_1 (Id=?)
- SCAN SUBQUERY 3

Comment: If the right hand side of the LEFT JOIN is a table instead of a view, then we don't need the additional criteria for the RHS table, correct?  

So, for example, this query doesn't require explicit filtering on Table1 to run efficiently:
`SELECT T3.Id FROM Table3 T3 LEFT JOIN Table1 T1 ON T3.Id=T1.Id WHERE T3.Id = 'asdf'`

I believe my confusion is that since we can treat views as tables when writing the select, I don't expect to do something different to query views efficiently.

Comment: @FernandoRodriguez No, this is not correct. Only `sqlite_autoindex_Table3_1` will be used in that query because again only T3 is filtered.

Comment: @FernandoRodriguez see the demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a0391943602e275b55d202461f331fdc

Comment: OK, perhaps this is more of a sqlite optimization gripe, but shouldn't sqlite figure out that the Id filter should apply to UnionView as well, instead of forcing me to duplicate the filter?  You did mention the where clause is performed after the join, so that could help explain the behavior.

Comment: @FernandoRodriguez No, the order of statements executed in any SQL query has the joins with the ON clauses applied first and after that the conditions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that demo site.  I tried it out and interestingly enough, I now get SEARCH TABLE instead of SCAN TABLE without using the View filter.  [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=af53eded00b4bd9277962b218c13a0a4).  Why the difference?  Perhaps it is due to sqlite version differences.

Comment: @FernandoRodriguez It has to be the version that makes the difference. I tested in 3.33.0 in SQLite Browser and in 3.34.1 in https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle=de665070408e0041a33a231575f2a5060b226e0baccd9108ef785ea87b1dfd81 and they both return scan table.